# How to test if ggplot was printed?

Tags: r, unit-testing, ggplot2, testthat

Let's consider very basic function :

```
plot_ggplot <- function() { 
    print(ggplot() + aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) + geom_point())
}
```

Is there any possibility to create sensible unit for **such defined** function ? I know that we can easily create unit testing when print is not included. Maybe is there possibility to check if something appears in plot window in R ?

I don't want to redefine the function because it's part of much bigger function.

Comment: Does the section "testing ggplot2 output" in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/ggplot2-in-packages.html) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to capture the device as a raster and check if all values are white, but I don't know how devices act in a testthat environment. You'd also have to `dev.off()` after every print and restart `cap <- ragg::agg_capture()` for every test, I think.

```r
library(ggplot2)

cap <- ragg::agg_capture()

has_printed <- function(x = cap()) {
  !all(x == "white")
}

plot_ggplot <- function() { 
  print(ggplot() + aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) + geom_point())
}

has_printed()
#> [1] FALSE

plot_ggplot()

has_printed()
#> [1] TRUE

dev.off()
#> png 
#>   2
cap <- ragg::agg_capture()

has_printed()
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: You can probably automate the resetting as part of the `has_printed()` function, but you'd have to be careful with superassignment (here be dragons).

```r
library(ggplot2)

cap <- ragg::agg_capture()

has_printed <- function(x = cap()) {
  out <- !all(x == "white")
  dev.off()
  cap <<- ragg::agg_capture()
  return(out)
}

plot_ggplot <- function() { 
  print(ggplot() + aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) + geom_point())
}

has_printed()
#> [1] FALSE

plot_ggplot()

has_printed()
#> [1] TRUE

has_printed()
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>